# Platforms collide-able on one side only

Tags: xna, c#, platformer

I have frequently tried to make some sort of a platformer, but when I actually code it, I run into a bit of a snag. How would I be able to make platforms in the air stop objects if they hit the sides or bottom, but allow them to sit on top of them?

I have tried many different methods, and some work slightly, but have many bugs, or some don't even work at all. Like this one I tried made it so that if you hit the side of the platform at the right angle, it forced you up on top of it.

Comment: What do you have right now? What have you tried? It's a simple collision checking problem, but people would like to see how your world is set, etc.

Comment: @Gustavo i just wanted to see suggestions for how to make a platforming collision. right now i have given up on platforming, simply because of this problems. i have tried using mostly rectangles before, but i haven't tried using just the positions before.

Comment: I'll also live this little treasure that landed up in my inbox today right here: http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much about how your code works it's hard to give an exact answer, but something like this should work:

```
if (collision(platform) && pos.y - height - vel.y < platform.y && vel.y > 0) {
    // Player collides, was over the platform the last update and is falling
    vel.y = 0;                      // Stop player
    pos.y = platform.y - height;    // Position player on platform
    onGround = true;
}
```

If the registration point of the player is centered you would use height/2 instead of height, and you might have to take the platforms height into account as well if it's registration point isn't at the top.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed a small error in the if statement, I have updated it to take into account the velocity in the second condition. The second condition should check that the player _was_ over the platform in the last frame, not that he is now.

Comment: Wow. I never thought to do that with checking if it was above before. This is before acceleration comes into effect in this frame, right?

Comment: The way I wrote the example you would check for collisions after everything else is updated, like velocities and positions. I think that is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Should i include acceleration?

Comment: Not in the code example above, it only cares about speed and position in order to figure out if the player collided from above in the current frame.